# Quick launch header edit

Tags: web-part, quick-launch, team-sites, edit

I am trying to set up a team site in sharepoint.

I want to put a link (header) in the quick launch for a web-part page. Is this possible?

I have added new headers in the quick launch, but I dont know how (where) to edit the page. I click on the link and i go to a page: "This page does no exists".

Is there an another way?

I am not myself a programmer and I dont have sharepoint designer.

Comment: Can you please edit the question to include version of SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I assume you are looking to have a header in the Web Part.

Please select edit page and edit your webpart option.
Inside appearance you have Chrome type select Title only option.

Edit Page will be an Option if you have appropriate access permission please check and
Could u share your SP version I would be able to help??